Is there a way to define a "toggle breakpoint" mapping in termdebug?
How to implement a there_is_a_breakpoint_on_this_line condition to be used in the following if-then-else block in termdebug?
if there_is_a_breakpoint_on_this_line
    <cmd>Clear
else
   <cmd>Break
endif

